# GSON: Serialize a single null field without using the global serializeNulls()

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm using Gson with Retrofit, and I have a case where I need to serialize a single null field, but I cannot turn on the global serializeNulls() flag for Gson, because it will break the rest of my code.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Here's what I've tried:

- Make an annotation, @SerializeNull.  This would be the ideal solution, but it failed because the serializeNulls flag is actually on the JsonWriter, which is downstream of the ExclusionStrategy.
- Use a TypeAdapterFactory.  Again, the JsonWriter is downstream.

I also couldn't figure out a way to add to the serialized json, since it all happens inside Retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting setSerializeNulls(true) and restoring original value to JsonWriter in TypeAdapter.write():

```
public class NullableDoubleAdapter extends TypeAdapter<NullableDouble> {

  @Override
  public void write(final JsonWriter out, final NullableDouble value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
      boolean serializeNulls = out.getSerializeNulls();
      out.setSerializeNulls(true);
      out.nullValue();
      out.setSerializeNulls(serializeNulls);
    } else {
      out.value(value.getValue());
    }
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension of Andriy's solution that doesn't just work for `NullableDouble`, but allows generically wrapping any type. The downside compared to plain `serializeNulls()` is that it requires creating the `GsonForceNull` instance as a wrapper and accessing the `value` inside throughout the Java code (though suitable getter/setter implementations can hide that detail).

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

// Forces Gson to output `null` in case the value is null, rather than omitting the field altogether.
public class GsonForceNull<V> {
    public V value;

    public GsonForceNull() {
    }

    public GsonForceNull(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    static class ForceNullTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
        @Override
        public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
            if (type.getRawType() != GsonForceNull.class) return null;
            //noinspection unchecked
            return this.createInternal(gson,
                    (TypeToken) TypeToken.get(((ParameterizedType) type.getType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]));
        }

        private <V> TypeAdapter<GsonForceNull<V>> createInternal(Gson gson, TypeToken<V> innerType) {
            final TypeAdapter<V> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, innerType);
            return new TypeAdapter<GsonForceNull<V>>() {
                @Override
                public void write(JsonWriter out, GsonForceNull<V> value) throws IOException {
                    V innerValue = value == null ? null : value.value;
                    if (innerValue == null && !out.getSerializeNulls()) {
                        out.setSerializeNulls(true);
                        out.nullValue();
                        out.setSerializeNulls(false);
                    } else {
                        delegate.write(out, innerValue);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public GsonForceNull<V> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                    return new GsonForceNull<>(delegate.read(in));
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new GsonForceNull.ForceNullTypeAdapterFactory());

class MyExampleRequestClass {
    private final GsonForceNull<Long> someField = new GsonForceNull<>();
    // getter/setter
}
```